# Finding a power series representation for $\left(\frac{x}{2-x}\right)^3$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Find a power series representation for $\displaystyle\left(\frac{x}{2-x}\right)^3$

My approach is in finding something similar to $\displaystyle\left(\frac{x}{2-x}\right)^3$ to which I can easily find the power series representation of.

I use $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2-x}$, noting that $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1}{2-x}\right)'=\frac{1}{(2-x)^2} \text { and } \left(\frac{1}{2-x}\right)''=\frac{2}{(2-x)^3}$.

So 
$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2-x}=\int\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}dx \iff \frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n=\int\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}dx$$

and differentiating both sides, I get the power series representation of the first derivative

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$$

for the second derivative,

$$\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}=\int\frac{2}{(2-x)^3} \iff \frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(n+1)\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n=\int\frac{2}{(2-x)^3}dx$$

differentiating both sides, I get the power series representation of the second derivative

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(n+1)n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{2}{(2-x)^3}$$

Is this so far correct? If it is, in the end I would multiply the power series representation of $\displaystyle\frac{2}{(2-x)^3}$ by $\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{2}$ to cancel out the $2$ and get the power series for $\displaystyle\left(\frac{x}{2-x}\right)^3$.

Comment: That looks pretty good to me.

Comment: For the expression after "I get the power series representation of the second derivative": Taking $x=0$ on the left hand side gives $\frac{1}{2}(1+1)1 = 1$ while your right hand side gives $\frac{2}{(2-0)^3} = \frac{1}{4}$. I think it should be $\frac{8}{(2-x)^3}$.

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n = \frac{1}{2}\cdot n \cdot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n-1}$. It seems you have forgotten the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ in front two times which would give the correct value of $8$ in the last expression.

Comment: @Winther Ah yes thank you, I forgot to apply chain rule. So I should have $\frac{1}{8}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(n+1)n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{2}{(2-x)^3}$ is what you say if done correctly? Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You're approach is fine (besides the missing integration constant according to @Winther's comment).

> Hint: Note, that you could also obtain a power series representation by applying the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* to your expression, since
>
> \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{x}{2-x}\right)^3
> =\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^3\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-3}
> =\ldots
> \end{align*}